# How can I use RecyclerView in fragments using Firestore - Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I want to use a recyclerView to show some products, they are inside firebase-firestore and, to get them I use a query. After this, I call the adapter to show but nothing appears.
You can see my adapter where:

```
public class ProdutoRecyclerAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter <Produto, ProdutoRecyclerAdapter.ProdutoHolder> {


public ProdutoRecyclerAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Produto> options) {
    super(options);
}

@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProdutoHolder produtoHolder, int i, @NonNull Produto produto) {
    produtoHolder.tNome.setText(produto.getNomeP());
    produtoHolder.tPontos.setText(String.valueOf(produto.getPontosP()));

}

@NonNull
@Override
public ProdutoHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.lista_produtos,parent,false);
    ProdutoHolder holder = new ProdutoHolder(v);

    return holder;
}

class ProdutoHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView tNome;
    TextView tPontos;

    public ProdutoHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        tNome = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nomeP);
        tPontos= itemView.findViewById(R.id.pontosP);


    }
}
```

And here there is my fragment:

```
    @Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.store,null);

    toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_loja);
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    Query query = produtoRef.orderBy("pontos");

    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Produto> option = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Produto>()
            .setQuery(query, Produto.class)
            .build();

    adapter = new ProdutoRecyclerAdapter(option);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.produtos_list);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return view;
}



@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    adapter.startListening();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    adapter.stopListening();
}
```

I don't have any error, but nothing appears on the screen, and I already did the debug and I know the variables are passing the right value.

Answer (score 0):

At your adapter, you should have the override of `getItemCount()` and `getItem()`

```
/**
     * Gets the item at the specified position from the backing snapshot array.
     *
     * @see ObservableSnapshotArray#get(int)
     */
    @NonNull
    public T getItem(int position) {
        return mSnapshots.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mSnapshots.isListening(this) ? mSnapshots.size() : 0;
    }
```

where `mSnapshots` is your array of data.

Docuementation [here](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/firestore/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/firestore/FirestoreRecyclerAdapter.java)

Comment: Can you explain a little more, please?
I saw the documentation and I don't understand

Comment: i saw this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lAGI6jGS4vs
And he don't use your metods